# Border is overlapping content

Tags: html, css

So i've run into an annoying issue where i've set a `wide border (15px)` on a `<div>` and I have an element that is `floated right` inside of that `<div>` with a `negative margin` to top so that it slightly overlaps the border. This was working fine until I set the `<div>` to `overflow-y:scroll` and now instead of the the text overlapping the border the `border overlaps` the text. I'm at a loss as to why this occurs and how to fix it.

- [**live demo**](http://thepelican.me/me/index.html) | the h1 element at the top of each `.window` is being overlapped by the border but if you disable the `overflow-y:scroll` on `.window` then it is fine.

**What i've tried so far**

- I tried giving the `h1` a higher z-index than the `.window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on the `h1`:

```
h1 {
font-size: 500%;
margin-top: -38px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: absolute;
width: inherit;
text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: this *is* close however I lose the `float:right`, and since the font/window isn't fixed sized I can't just `margin-left` it the right way back. Calculating this in js seems silly however it seems as though it may be the road I will have to take. Why does the border z-index change when modifying overflow states o.O weird.

Comment: why do you need the `float:right`? try my updated answer with `text-align:right`

Answer (score 0):

Giving your `h1` element a `position: absolute` should help.

Comment: Just that is going to complicate things

Comment: doing this breaks the layout and I can't imagine it is necessary for this, there should be a solution in which I do not have to restructure my dom simply because I've added a scroll attribute..

Comment: Adding absolute is what is going to make that work, otherwise I'd recommend just adding the border as a background image in the whatever full width element surrounds your h1. Note: the solution you have working form Moin (which is good) relies on the absolute positioning.

Comment: Yep I know man, and the reason I settled for his is because he actually gave a real solution whereas simply giving me a 'clue' doesn't really help that much. cheers for trying though :)